# In JavaFX, how do I have different context menus for different TreeItem types?

Tags: javafx, treeview, contextmenu

I'm trying to assign different context menus based on a parameter in the TreeItem class that I attach to the TreeItem. But I'm not having any success and I can't seem to find any info for how to do this. I've seen examples where a different context menu is used on the treeRoot then a different menu on the first branch but I can't find anything that would indicate how to have different context menus for the first then second branch in a TreeView.

I created these working classes to demonstrate where I'm at with this now, but it doesn't work as it never seems to actually pass the leaf nodes into the CellNode based on the output Im getting and the fact that the same menu is being applied to both levels of TreeItems.

Here is the GUI class:

```
public class MainUI {

    public MainUI() {
        makeControls();
        ap =  new AnchorPane(treeView);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Scene scene = new Scene(ap);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        stage.getScene().getWindow().centerOnScreen();
        stage.getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
    }

    private final AnchorPane         ap;
    private       TreeView           treeView;
    private       TreeItem<TypeNode> treeRoot;


    private void makeControls() {
        treeView = new TreeView<>();
        treeRoot = new TreeItem<>(new TypeNode());
        treeView.setRoot(treeRoot);
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);
        treeView.setCellFactory(new CellFactory());
        fillTree();

    }

    private void fillTree() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int x=1; x <= 10; x++) {
                TreeItem<TypeNode> branch = new TreeItem<>(new TypeNode(Type.TYPE_A));
                for(int y=1; y <= 5; y++) {
                    TreeItem<TypeNode> leaf = new TreeItem<>(new TypeNode(Type.TYPE_B));
                    branch.getChildren().add(leaf);
                }
                treeRoot.getChildren().add(branch);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

The CellFactory:

```
public class CellFactory implements Callback<TreeView<TypeNode>, TreeCell<TypeNode>> {
    @Override public TreeCell<TypeNode> call(TreeView<TypeNode> treeView) {
        TreeCell<TypeNode> cell = new CellNode<>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(final TypeNode item, final boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null) return;
                setText(getTreeItem().getValue().getText());
                setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
            }
        };
        return cell;
    }
}
```

The CellNode:

```
public class CellNode<T> extends TreeCell<TypeNode> {

    private final ContextMenu menuA = new ContextMenu();
    private final ContextMenu menuB = new ContextMenu();

    public CellNode() {
        MenuItem menuA1  = new MenuItem("New A Item");
        MenuItem menuA2 = new MenuItem("Copy A Item");
        MenuItem menuB1  = new MenuItem("New B Item");
        MenuItem menuB2 = new MenuItem("Copy B Item");
        menuA.getItems().setAll(menuA1,menuA2);
        menuB.getItems().setAll(menuB1,menuB2);
        menuA1.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("menuA1"));
        menuA2.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("menuA2"));
        menuB1.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("menuB1"));
        menuB2.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("menuB2"));
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(TypeNode item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (!isEditing()) {
                System.out.println(getTreeItem().getValue().getType());
                if (!getTreeItem().isLeaf() && getTreeItem().getParent() != null) {
                    if(getTreeItem().getValue().getType().equals(Type.TYPE_A)) {
                        setContextMenu(menuA);
                    }
                    if(getTreeItem().getValue().getType().equals(Type.TYPE_B)) {
                        setContextMenu(menuB);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

TypeNode:

```
public class TypeNode {

    private       String text = "";
    private final Type   type;

    private static int var = 0;

    public TypeNode() {
        this.type = Type.NO_TYPE;
    }

    public TypeNode(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
        var++;
        this.text = this.type.toString() + ": " + var;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

And Type enum:

```
public enum Type {
    TYPE_A,
    TYPE_B,
    NO_TYPE
}
```

Here is the output from the loading of the Scene:

```
TYPE_A
TYPE_A
TYPE_A
TYPE_A
TYPE_A
TYPE_A
TYPE_A
TYPE_A
TYPE_A
TYPE_A
TYPE_A
TYPE_A
TYPE_A
TYPE_A
```

And here you can see that menuB never gets assigned to anything:

[image]

[image]

CLEARLY, I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out... any assistance or advice would be much appreciated.

Mike

Comment: [mcve] please (mind the __M__!) btw unrelated: do not change any property of a node off the fx application thread

Comment: all that said: the logic of setting the contextMenu looks fishy - you never seem to be setting it for a leaf (wondering why it shows menuA, though). In your shoes, I would really strip it down (don't extend the custom cell, a single branch with a single child is enough, no thread, nothing fancy), check if the branch setting the b is ever reached ..

Comment: Yes, the logic of the `updateItem(...)` is incorrect. You need to update the context menu for any code path. For example, if you have a cell which is used for an item which is not a leaf and not the root, and it's reused for a leaf node, the context menu will not be updated, and will still have the (essentially arbitrary) menu from the previous item it was used to display.

Comment: @kleopatra - I realize there are a lot of classes here but I'm fairly new to messing with TreeViews and TreeItems and clearly lack the knowledge to thoroughly understand whats happening... though Ive done quite a bit of reading up on it, I haven't found a document that explains these classes and how they interact with each other well enough ... lots of examples out there, but no real explanations of how it all comes together. Maybe that kind of info can only be found in a book? I do apologize for my lack of understanding here. I'll try what you suggested and see what happens.

Comment: So your `updateItem()` method needs to set the context menu for *every possible circumstance*. If there's a circumstance in which it could be invoked and `setContextMenu()` is not called, there is the possibility it will show the wrong menu.

Comment: @James_D - " if you have a cell which is used for an item which is not a leaf and not the root, and it's reused for a leaf node" - that I understand ... how do I differentiate the different levels of TreeItems so that it can know to assign the different menus?

Comment: You're already doing that: `if (!getTreeItem().isLeaf() && getTreeItem().getParent() != null)`. But my point is that if the expression inside that `if (...)` is false, you don't call `setContextMenu(...)`. So the context menu will just be the one displayed for whatever (arbitrary) item the cell previously displayed. That `updateItem(...)` method must *always* set the context menu to something (even if it's null). I bet if you expand all your tree nodes, collapse them all again, then there will be spurious context menus on the empty cells.

Comment: @James_D - but notice where my System.out statement is and see that the Type_B instance never reaches that if then statement...

Comment: That's irrelevant, isn't it? What you have to do is write that `updateItem(...)` method so that *any time it's invoked, `setContextMenu(...)` is guaranteed to be invoked*. Right now, just as an example, if it's invoked for a leaf node, `setContextMenu(...)` is not invoked.

Comment: Imagine this scenario. A given cell instance is assigned a non-leaf, non-parent item of type A. The `updateItem()` method will be called, which by the logic you implemented, sets the context menu to `menuA`. Suppose the same cell instance is then reused for a *leaf* node of type B. The `updateItem(...)` method will be invoked, and by the logic you implemented it doesn't call `setContextMenu(...)`. So the context menu doesn't change and is still set to `menuA`. This is exactly what is shown in your screenshot.

Comment: @James_D - Thanks for clarifying ... Not sure how I missed it, but now that I see, it seems very obvious what I was doing wrong. See the edit at the end of the post. Should I post this as the answer?

Comment: It’s still wrong, isn’t it?  What if a cell gets assigned a menu, then gets reused as an empty cell? It would have a spurious context menu. And to be really bullet-proof you should probably handle cases such as a non-empty cell with a null item, a non-null item with a null type, etc. As I said before, you simply need to ensure `updateItem(…)` *always* calls `setContextMenu(…)`.

Comment: @James_D - so how would I identify the situation where a cell gets reused as an empty cell? How would I test for that?

Comment: @MichaelSims Umm, `isEmpty()` will return true. Not really sure what you are failing to understand here.

Comment: @James_D - I didn't realize that when isEmpty() returns true, that it re-uses the last used ContextMenu.

Comment: @MichaelSims What else would it do? If you set a context menu, and don’t set it again, it retains the previous value. There’s nothing magic here - a cell behaves just the same as any other Java object.

Comment: @James_D - Yeah, thats my lack of really understanding whats going on under the hood in this scenario ... I'd really like to find something that explains how all of these classes interact so that I understand enough to know how to configure a TreeView properly.  I don't even really know what a CallFactory is in the first place ... or a Factory for that matter. I updated the edit, does it look correct now?

Comment: There's not a lot to it. A [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) is an object that creates other objects. So a cell factory is responsible for creating cells. `TreeView`s use cells to display items, and can reuse them in arbitrary fashion as some items become visible and others invisible (e.g. by scrolling, or expanding/collapsing nodes). The `updateItem(...)` method is called when the cell is used to display an item. That's really all there is to it. See the [`Cell` docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html).

Answer (score -1):

After some discussion in the comments under my post, I ended up changing the updateItem method in the CellNode class to this, and it now works properly (Thanks to James_D for helping me spot what should have been obvious):

```
public void updateItem(TypeNode item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
        setContextMenu(null);
    }
    else {
        if (item != null) {
            System.out.println(item.getType());
            switch (item.getType()) {
                case TYPE_A:
                    setContextMenu(menuA);
                    break;

                case TYPE_B:
                    setContextMenu(menuB);
                    break;

                default:
                    setContextMenu(null);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {
            setContextMenu(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still not entirely complete, missing the null item..

Comment: .. btw: (just checked) the api mehod doc has a snippet with a safe pattern ..

Comment: @kleopatra - How does it look now?

Comment: If item is null you should do something.  For example `if (empty || item == null) { . . . }`.  Then remove the if statement in your else clause.  If the item is not null, you should set the text or graphic or both.